# Mediaelement.js in WP 3.6 (core) malfunction on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress, ipad, mediaelement.js

In short, I'm using the new WordPress 3.6 [audio] shortcode (which is mediaelement.js) inside an HTML table that is enhanced with a javascript library called [datatables](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15784/tablepress-datatables-works-on-everything-but-idevices#Item_20).

This is my page: http://thetracksmiths.com/beats/fight-club/

If you view the above page on any PC or mac (in any browser), all is well with the world.  View it on an iPhone or iPad, and the players inside the table will not work.  After an exhausting search for answers, here's what the author of datatables had to say after some testing *(notice what's in bold at the bottom)*:

> So I've just had a bit more of a look into this, and I can fairly
>   easily replicate the issue without DataTables. All that needs to be
>   done is to remove the element from the document and then add it back
>   in again. The media player simply fails to play after that on iOS (and
>   this removal and addition is fundamental to how DataTables works).
>
> For example, if you disable DataTables on your page and add this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {
    var a = $('#tablepress-2 tbody tr:eq(2)')[0];
    a.parentNode.removeChild( a );

    $('#tablepress-2 tbody').append( a );
} );
```

> All of the players in the table will work, expect the very last row
>   (the one that has been removed and re-added).
>
> So its not something that DataTables is doing wrong, but **it is a
>   problem in the media player that is triggered by the actions
>   DataTables take**. As I say, this is fundamental to DataTables and isn't
>   likely to change, **so we need to know either if the author of the media
>   player library can fix it for when items are removed and then added
>   back into the DOM. Or if there is some sort of re-initialisation that
>   can be called when the element is added back into the DOM.**

If I'm understanding all this correctly (I'm no coder!), what the author is saying is that something in the audio code is playing nasty with iOS when it's taken off the page and then re-added.  Is this a genuine bug?  How can this be fixed?

Comment: The plugin author is saying the issue is with mediaplayer.js not datatables, and yes, that it happens do to the element being removed and re-added to the DOM.  unless there is some kind of initialization/re-init function that can be called in mediaplayer.js immediately after inserting it back into the DOM this is probably not an easy fix.

Comment: Looking at mediaplayer.js's documentation really fast I don't see any built in reinitialization method that can be called. Most likely the easiest way to get around this is to use some other media player plugin that does not suffer from this bug rather than using the default Wordpress implementation of mediaplayer.js.

Comment: @ennui I've tried every player I can get my hands on. They all have the same issue. I was hoping to stick solely with WordPress on this one to keep things simple.

Comment: Did it happen with the MeJS plugin on previous versions of wordpress?